# Importing CSV file from a website in Spyder?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, spyder

I am trying to import a dataset from the UCLA repository. I was able to do it succesfully in Jupyter Notebook but when I am trying to do the same in Spyder, I get no output. The code I have used is this:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports- 
85.data"
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df.head(20)
```

So, in Jupyter, I got the first 20 rows of the dataset on executing these steps but when I press the same in Sypder, nothing comes out as output. I did some digging around and found out that you got to change the forward slashes to backward slashes in Windows but even after doing that, nothing changes. I will really appreciate it if anyone can point out what it is I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write the code in Spyder's editor window, Spyder will run the code in a batch way, so you need to add the print() statement to get output.

```
print(df.head(20))
```

You should however get the correct output, if you run the original command manually in Spyder's iPython window.